# boost - get components multigraph from disjoint set

Tags: boost, disjoint-sets

I'm new in boost library. I have created a disjoint set structure on a graph to have some partitions on it, what is the best way to obtain the multigraph of the set components?

Comment: no code whatsoever? There could be a zillion ways you have done what you describe.

Comment: yes, I know, I would one of them :) my teacher said to me that I could use filtered graph, but I have understood that a filtered graph is based on predicates that says if an Edge or a Vertex of the original graph has to be included in the filtered graph, so I can't create the multigraph that I want, right?